# How to make asp.net tree view control to allow only one node to be expanded

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

I have binded the tree view control with my datatable and it has rendered perfectly.

But it allows me to expand as many nodes i click.

Only one node should be expanded at a time. clicking on another node should collapse other nodes.

What event should be fired for this ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Protected Sub Tree_Index_TreeNodeExpanded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles Tree_Index.TreeNodeExpanded
    ' Loop through all nodes 
    For Each treenode As TreeNode In Tree_Index.Nodes 
        ' If node is expanded 
        If treenode.Value <> e.Node.Value Then
            ' Collapse all other nodes 
            treenode.Collapse()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```